# How to check if a path exists to certain point on NavMesh for a NavMeshAgent in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, path-finding, agent, navmesh

I have a NavMeshAgent that I am using SetDestination() with, but the agent always tries to get as close to the destination as possible, even the location is unreachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use NavMeshPathStatus.PathComplete to check if the path ends at the destination.

Here's Unity answers for a similar question
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1197626/navmesh-how-to-check-if-full-path-available-c.html